# why the following works when not using props

Tags: reactjs, redux

for the following code

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { articles: state.articles };
};

const ConnectedList = ({ articles }) => (
  <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
    {articles.map(el => (
      <li className="list-group-item" key={el.id}>
        {el.title}
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
);
```

I am wondering if articles is a local variable, why it is not belong to props?

Comment: `react-redux` will make sure it ends up in the component's props. Am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: `articles` is part of props. They are just using destructuring assignment for the only argument, `props`...

Comment: [Take a look at the docs for destructuring assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for a better understanding of how this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functional/Stateless components in react are passed props as the first argument. In your example, you are using object deconstruction to grab articles from the props object.

A stateless component is a function that takes props and optionally context, and returns a react component or null (not undefined). You can set additional properties like `propTypes` on that function after it is defined, and react will respect them.